# Extracting text between two strings/title

Tags: python, text, extract

I have a list of titles and i have to extract the text between those titles. But these titles do not follow an order (sometimes title 1 can be title 3 and so on), in this case how do i approach this extraction?

Example

```
Biography

text

text

Place of Birth

Text

Text

Life Style

text

text

Marriage

Text

Text
```

I Can use the below code if all the title were placed in order, but in my case these titles do not follow an order, it keeps changing for different input files.

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Biography":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "Place of Birth":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: What determines a "title"? What *is* the pattern?

Comment: What is the issue with this code?

Comment: This code works fine for above example, but as i told these titles are not in a order. For example.

**Biography** 
(text)

**Marriage**
(text)

**Place of Birth**
(text)
In this example, the engine will extract the text within the title marriage as well.

Comment: You will have to define each title separately in your code and set copy=True or False, for each title separately.

Comment: What determines a "title"? What is the pattern? 

I have the list of titles which occur in the document. But the problem is these titles do not follow an order

Comment: @AnandSKumar Do we have an alternative, like i make a directory of these titles in a xml and cross check it in the doc and then extract it?

Comment: Well, yea if you only want to extract some, then for those you set copy to True, for all other titles (make sure to match all titles) all other titles make copy false.

Comment: Am i getting it right? You want to extraxt text of chapters but for some chapters you want to skip the text.

Comment: @Mehdi I want to extract all the chapters and i have all the titles in place, but these chapters do not follow the same order in other articles.

Comment: I don't understand `copy = False` part

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks a lot, your way of setting True or False worked out, thats great :) But i have a doubt, how do i save each title separately maybe in a csv by separating different titles in different columns?

Comment: Posted a solution as an answer , please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to  only extract data for some titles and avoid the data for others, then for those you set copy to True, for all other titles (make sure to match all titles) all other titles make copy false.

Example -

```
if title in [<list of titles to save data>]:
    copy = True
elif title in [<list of titles to not save data>]:
    copy = False
```

To save the data using titles as column names and the data inside as the records, you can first store each column and its data in a row inside another list , and then later on transpose that list using - `list(zip(*lst))` where `lst` is your list and then  you can use `numpy` to create an array with this list and save the data into a csv with delimiter as `,`.

Example code -

```
import numpy
lst = []
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() in ["Biography"]:
            copy = True
            lst.append([line.strip()])
        elif line.strip() in ["Place of Birth"]:
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            lst[-1].append(line.strip())

lst = list(zip(*lst))
n = numpy.array(lst)
numpy.savetext("foo.csv", n, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: There is an error when i tried to append using the above code: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'savetext'"

Comment: Hey, after little editing, its working fine. But where does this csv save/store as we havent defined a output path? (Sorry i'm new to this dont mind asking silly questions)

Comment: You define the file name in the `numpy.savetext()` function call - `"foo.csv"` , when we use relative path (that is complete path is not given) , it stores the data relative to current directory , where we run the script from. In this case, it stores in a file called foo.csv on the same folder.

Comment: Hey Anand, your code works cool. Thanks a ton :) Sorry to bother you much, i would like to know how do i save the output to any string like X or Y, so that i can use the extracted text for further analyzing, before saving it to a csv.

Comment: You have the list `lst` you can use that. it would there is a single line of code that is transposing the script, so that we get each title and its corresponding data in columns - lst = list(zip(*lst)) , instead of saving to same variable, you can save it to different variable , say lst1 , then use lst1 to create the numpy array and save to csv, you can then do whatever logic you want on that lst list (if you are changing the lst list and  want the changes saved) I recommend only saving the lst to csv at the end

Comment: Cool done. Yeah i want to save to csv only at the end, that is why i want the output to be move to a string like x, y or z so that i can use the extracted text for analyzing and then after analyzing want to save it to csv. It would be really great if you could guide me on how do i pass the output to a string, rather to a csv or a text file (as i want to do this at the end). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: try checking `'\n'.join([','.join(l) for l in lst])` to get the stirng that would be outputed to the csv. Please use the `lst` list after transposing

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all "titles" are known in advance, it's enough to change your original line:

```
elif line.strip() == "Place of Birth":
```

in this way:

```
elif line.strip() in ["Place of Birth", "Life Style", "Marriage", ...]:
```

Comment: I should be able obtain the text inside each title and save it in a csv by placing the text of each title in a column .

your code is fine, but strip till? we have to define an ending string as well, right?

Comment: no, that is not how strip works. Strip trims out leading and preceding whitespaces (space\tab\newline if any)

Comment: Lines end with `\n` or `\r\n` when you read from file. it's safer if you trim that with `.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each title starts with a capital letter.

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == line[0].capitalize():
            copy = True
        else:
            copy = False

        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Yeah it does, but there are other texts which starts in capital letter as well, in that case this might not work.

Comment: Even then, assuming only titles started with capital letters, this is not what the OP asked, it only copies the titles to the out file, nothing else . OP clearly asked for the text in between each title to be copied